# How to replicate python's `ssl.get_default_context()` in Windows C++?

Tags: python, c++, ssl, websocket, mqtt

My final goal is to port over a simple `mqtt-paho-python` script to C++ for integration within a large application.

The python example using paho is quite simple:

```
client = mqtt.Client(transport="websockets")
client.username_pw_set(settings['username'], password=settings['password'])
client.tls_set_context(context=ssl.create_default_context())
```

They set up the default TLS context, authenticate with a username and password, and then connect.  This works great!

However, now I want to try to get the same secure configuration using `paho-mqtt-cpp`.  The basic example, borrowing from their async examples, goes like this:

```
mqtt::connect_options connOpts;
connOpts.set_keep_alive_interval(20);
connOpts.set_clean_session(true);
connOpts.set_user_name("username");
connOpts.set_password("password123");

mqtt::ssl_options sslOpts;
connOpts.set_ssl(sslOpts);

mqtt::async_client client("wss://test.mosquitto.org:8081", "myClient");

callback cb(client, connOpts);
client.set_callback(cb);
```

However, `ssl.get_default_context()` in python's ssl library seems to do quite a bit of setup for me that isn't replicated in C++; from python's own documentation:

"For client use, if you don’t have any special requirements for your security policy, it is highly recommended that you use the create_default_context() function to create your SSL context. It will load the system’s trusted CA certificates, enable certificate validation and hostname checking, and try to choose reasonably secure protocol and cipher settings."

Most WSS connections I've tried require a certificate, and `create_default_context()` seems to be able to provide the proper certificates without me generating any myself.

So my questions:
(1) Where are Windows' System Default Certificates that I can use for secure connections? and
(2) What other settings do I need to manually configure that `create_default_context()` might be setting up for me under the hood?

I've tried looking at the [source](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.8/Lib/ssl.py#L723), but it's not easily discernible where the OS-specific options are.

Comment: I still don't know where Windows keeps its own default certificates, but I circumvented the issue by download TLS certificates from Mozilla and packaging them with my application: https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/about/governance/policies/security-group/certs/